# Remove certain characters in a filename in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I have files in a directory such as

```
FILE1.docx.txt
FILE2.docx.txt
FILE3.docx.txt
FILE4.docx.txt
FILE5.docx.txt
```

And I would like to remove `.docx` from all of them to make the final output such as

```
FILE1.txt
FILE2.txt
FILE3.txt
FILE4.txt
FILE5.txt
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this python script in the same folder that contains files:

```
import os

for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    aux = file.split('.')
    if len(aux) == 3:
        os.rename(file, aux[0] + '.' + aux[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

With [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and `mv`

```sh
for f in *.docx.txt; do
  echo mv -vn "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"
done
```

The one-liner

```sh
for f in *.docx.txt; do echo mv -vn "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` if you think the output is correct, to rename the files.

Should work in any `POSIX` compliant shell, without any script.

---

With bash, enable the `nullglob` shell option so the glob `*.docx.txt` will not expand as literal `*.docx.txt` if there are no files ending with `.docx.txt`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in *.docx.txt; do
  echo mv -vn "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"
done
```

---

UPDATE: Thanks to  `@Léa Gris` add `nullglob` change the glob to `*.docx.txt` and add `-n` to `mv`, Although `-n` and `-v` is not defined by `POSIX` as per https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html It should be in both GNU and BSD `mv`

Comment: Don't forget `shopt -s nullglob` in case no file match the `*.txt` globbing pattern. Also you can restrict the globbing pattern to candidates only with `for f in *.docx.txt`, Prefer `mv -n` to not overwrite existing files.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of sed and bash like this:

```
for i in *.docx.txt
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/.docx//'`"
done
```